# could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)

Tags: deployment, blockchain, smartcontracts, hardhat, ganache

**while deploying contract on Ganache I'm getting this error**

```
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
at Logger.makeError (/mnt/c/Codeeater/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
at Logger.throwError (/mnt/c/Codeeater/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
at EthersProviderWrapper.\<anonymous\> (/mnt/c/Codeeater/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:483:23)
at step (/mnt/c/Codeeater/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
at Object.throw (/mnt/c/Codeeater/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
at rejected (/mnt/c/Codeeater/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
reason: 'could not detect network',
code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
event: 'noNetwork'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**--> hardhat.confing.js file is**

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

require("dotenv").config();

/\*\* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig \*/

const Sepolia_url = process.env.Sepolia_url;

const private_key = process.env.private_key;

const Ganache_url = process.env.Ganache_url;

const Ganache_private_key = process.env.Ganache_private_key;

module.exports = {

solidity: "0.8.17",

networks: {

sepolia: {       url: Sepolia_url,

    accounts: \[private_key\],  

},

Ganache: {

url: Ganache_url,

     accounts: \[Ganache_private_key\],  

},

},

};
```

**-->.env file is**

```
Ganache_url = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"
Ganache_private_key = "075d807fa06bcbb594c268c2f07a52cd4c9fe7d4f23b1e5e974a34cf6ba5c210"
```

**-->Command I run is**

```
yarn hardhat run --network Ganache scripts/major_project.js
```

Comment: can you `console.log(process.env.Ganache_url)` in hardhat.config.js. and make sure name of the config file is correct and located in correct place

Comment: Thanks I'm able to deploy it in Ganache just by changing its SERVER